# URL amigável funciona e para

Tags: php, htaccess, url-amigável

Bom, estou com um problema em relação ao `.htaccess e a URL amigável`, ela funciona, porém as vezes para e volta a funcionar. (Módulo Rewrite está ativo, uso PHP 7). E estou com mais uma dúvida, tenho uma **pasta** na raiz chamada `view`, dentro dela tenho um arquivo chamado `v_login.php`, como que eu posso fazer para a url ficar `localhost/projeto/login`? Isso seria passado por parâmetro como **v_login** por exemplo e na index eu procuraria esse arquivo colocando o caminho **view/** e a extensão **.php**, e daria um **require_once** nele?

.htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo 'Homepage';
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Consegui resolver.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

index.php

```
 <?php
    $home = 'view/home.php';
    $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : $home;
    if ($url != $home) {
        $dir = 'view/';
        $url = array_filter(explode('/', $url));
        $url = $dir. $url[0] . '.php'; 
    }
    // var_dump($url);
    if (file_exists($url)) {
        include_once $url;
    } else {
        include_once 'view/404.php';
    }
 ?>
```